# SQL SELECT MIN value with WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the lowest price of a specific quote on SQL. I tried the following with erroneous results:

- SELECT * FROM price WHERE price=(SELECT MIN(price) as price FROM price WHERE id_quote=36
- SELECT id_provider, MIN(price) as price FROM price WHERE id_quote=36

I understand that I'm getting multiple results on the first query if I have the same price in that table regardless of the quote. But I don't know why the second isn't giving me the correct results.

I need to call only id_provider and its price from that specific quote (no group).

Any help?

[image: Table price]

Comment: In the second one you are selecting id_provider. Which one are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM price p
WHERE p.id_quote = 36 AND
      p.price = (SELECT MIN(p2.price) FROM price p2 WHERE p2.id_quote = p.id_quote);
```

Notice that the "quote" condition has moved to the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

I like using RANK() for this kind of problem:

```
SELECT id_quote, id_provider, price
FROM
(
SELECT id_quote id_provider, price,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id_quote ORDER BY price ASC) AS rnk
FROM price
) sub
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: I don't believe MySQL added window functions until MySQL 8. So this may not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it this way if you want:

SELECT TOP 1 id_provider, price FROM price WHERE id_quote=36 ORDER BY price ASC
```